# React Native - Initiating calls to Javascript from Native for certain use-cases

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a number of RN U.I. components and modules (in java for android and Obj-C/Swift for IOS) and would like to make use of Javascript to perform various tasks (predominantly network related). My current use case involves video playback, with a requirement that decryption keys be loaded from a server. The request for decryption keys originates on the native side (by AVFoundation/AVPlayer in the case of IOS and by exoplayer in the case of android) and requires the return of arbitrary binary data to the ios/android native side.

I would ideally like to develop this key request functionality once, on the javascript side. So, is there a way to initiate the execution of JS code, from the native side, and have a result returned back to the native side. This would also need to be asynchronous, using some kind of callback mechanism.

It doesn't look like the RN event and callback mechanisms allows the passing back of data from js to native. Am I correct on this? And if so, is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios

Comment: or this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript

Comment: Thanks for your insights but I've read all the docs (am a seasoned RN developer).  The issue is with initiating from the Native (java or obj-c/swift) side, a call to JS, for which a result is returned to Native.  RN is not geared for this but I'm wondering if this is possible.  RN callback semantics don't provide for return values, and EventEmitter is also not designed with this in mind.